# Visual Studio Online You do not have the required permissions to perform this action As Owner

Tags: migration, azure-devops, opshub

Visual Studio Online.  You do not have the required permissions to perform this action as the Owner.  When trying to add a user to a VSO group.

I'm trying to add a user to the Project Collection Service Accounts.  The add member is grayed out on the group and on the user it gives this error.  How do I add a member to this group.  I'm logged in as the VSO Owner.

I need this for the OpsHub migration utility.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the latest version of OVSMU from Microsoft Gallery which handles this change of interface/permission of VSO, or for a workaround in the current version do the following:

- Create a new (custom) VSO Group
- Under '**Members**', add your user.
- Under '**Member of**', add **[DefaultCollection]Project Collection Service Accounts**
- Go back to OVSMU and re-validate the migration that you were creating.

Comment: I went the custom group route.  Worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account you login has the permission "Edit collection-level information".